# PHP string contains two characters then a slash at the beginning

Tags: php, strpos

Imagine the following string

```
/en/pages/title-page  or /es/pages/title-page
```

How to determine if the string has a slash then two unknown characters (always two) and then another slash. Then once known, can these be extracted from the string.

Comment: Regular expressions? :)

Comment: try to use this https://regex101.com/r/obz7Mw/1

Comment: this is from an url, isn't it? If the url will *always* contain a language, you can use [substr()](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php). `$match = substr($url, 1, 2);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will have the language in index `1` of the `$matches` array. Otherwise, if the pattern does not match, the array will be empty.

```
$matches = null;
if (preg_match('/^\/([a-zA-Z]{2})\//', '/en/pages/title-page', $matches) === 1)
    echo $matches[1];
else
    echo 'No language found';
```

Comment: \w matches: letter, number, underscore